# Adding a php library into laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I would like to ask how to install php markdown library into Laravel 4?

I know how to install a laravel package, but I have no idea on how to install a php file.

Do anyone know how to install it? or using composer?

Library source: http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library is exist on packagist anyway: https://packagist.org/packages/michelf/php-markdown , so you can use composer. Edit composer.json add following line to "require" property:

```
"michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.*"
```

run:

```
composer update
```

Now you can use it like:

```
 \Michelf\Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem too. But what I do is just include this line

require_once('C:\wamp\www\app\helpers\markdown.php');

Thanks again!

Comment: I believe the way I describe above is recommended way since you get your library manageable by composer.